# langchat openai yes no answer

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I have a strange behaviour and don't even know how to debug.
Basically I use a agent and the final answer will be always appended with "Does it answer your Question ?"

so the answer coming back looks like:  The Lean Startup is a methodology for developing businesses and products that aims to shorten product development cycles and rapidly discover if a proposed business model is viable. It emphasizes early customer feedback and iterative product development. Does it answer your question?

answer=agent('Yes, this answers my question. ')  works as expected,
but answer=agent('Yes')

gives me :

File "C:\Users\svena\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\KnowledgeBase\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\mrkl\output_parser.py", line 42, in parse
raise OutputParserException(
langchain.schema.OutputParserException: Could not parse LLM output: `I'm sorry, but I need more information or a specific question in order to provide a helpful answer. Can you please provide more details or ask a specific question related to Lean Startups? Does it answer your question?`

Thanks in advance for any hint in which direction i should look. I did search, but could not find anything helpful.

a way to deal with a yes/no or y/N or other indications of this meaning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.